# Testing a Java Entity class outside of an Application Server (Using JUnit)

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, orm, junit

I'm writing a few unit tests to test an entity class and I'm running these tests from within Eclipse.

In my persistence.xml I am referencing the JNDI name of a datasource that is set up in GlassFish.

When running the unit test from Eclipse, I get the following exception:

```
Exception Description: Cannot acquire data source [JNDI-NAME-FROM-APP-SERVER].
```

Could this be because I am not within the context of the appserver and if so, what would be the 'nicest' way to get around this?

Comment: What unit test runner are you using? Are you using [Arquillan](http://www.jboss.org/arquillian.html)? Or are you just mocking everything?

Comment: At the moment it's very basic. I'm just running a Junit test case (class) from within Eclipse that instantiates an entityManagerFactory. Ideally, I would introduce something for more slick but this is really just a first pass.

Comment: Yup, if your persistence.xml references a JNDI name for your datasource, then that needs to be resolved in order to make the connection.
Beyond that this isn't a directly answerable question and should be closed.
You do have many options: use a different connection (JDBC connections string vs JNDI) in your tests, setup the JNDI name in your tests, etc.
However, it might be worth while looking into 1) frameworks like Spring which simplify prod vs test environments, 2) mocking tools as Adam suggested, 3) in-memory databases like Derby so you don't need to connect to a real database to run tests.

Comment: So it sounds like my options are as follows: use a tool that will allow me to access the connection pool in GlassFish from the tests (is this even possible?), use JDBC to make a direct connection (this won't always be possible due to VPN limitations) or create a local or in memory database to effectively mock the real database. Also, I'm not keen on throwing Spring into my JEE6 project.

Comment: The Jboss guys claim (and they hate Spring) [Arquillan](http://www.jboss.org/arquillian.html) : http://www.jboss.org/arquillian.html is the thing to use for JEE6 integration testing which seems to be what you are trying to do. Otherwise @SeanConnolly is right that Spring excels in this area.

Comment: @OP: If you are doing 'unit' testing then you should not be relying on datasource created in App Server. That kind of defeat the purpose of unit testing. Mocks are true way doing unit testing but comes with some overhead. If you still want to use datasource, create a datasource using plain properties.

Answer (score 0):

Pass a properties Map to Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(pu, properties) with your test database url and user/password.

Or have a separate persistence unit defined for Java SE testing.